# Usercontrol issue

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have got a very big confusing question....

is .xaml file is a page or a usercontrol.
Simple words is silver light has pages or every silver light page is called as a usercontrol????

I have a scenario:
firstly i have mainpage and app.xaml.

I have added myPage.xaml as a sivlerlight usercontrol. This has same extension and code behind same as main page. I am able to find mypage as a silverlight usercontrol in Toolbox menu but not Mainpage... Is there any specific reason i cannot use mainpage as a usercontrol...???

Any answers appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you right click the project and select Add New Item, you can choose to add either a Silverlight page or a user control. Both are written in xaml, but one starts with `<Page>` and the other with `<UserControl>`

** edited with HiTech Magic's correction

A User Control is the base class for writing your own .xaml object. A Page inherits from a User Control, but has additional functionality (you can navigate to it inside a Frame)

Hope this helps.

Comment: "can only be shown within a page" is incorrect. Just to clarify the above, UserControls are also used as Pages (but without the navigation extras).